Calculate ways to split n identical items into m groups that may be empty
Say I want to take 100 (n) identical items and divide them into 4 (m) separate groups.   The items are identical, so there is only one case for 98,1,0,1, but the groups are not so 98,1,1,0 is different.  Is there a formula for this?  From writing a program that checked each option I got the value 176,952.
For m=2 the answer is 101, group 0 can have any value from 0-100 and group 1 then has the remaining items.   I can't wrap my head around how to create a formula for this though.  When I expand to 3 groups, there is 1 way for group 0 to have 100.   Then there are two ways for group 0 to have 99 (99,1,0 and 99,0,1).   Then there are 3 ways for group 0 to have 98 (98,2,0 and 98,1,1 and 98,0,2).
And 4 ways for group 0 to have 97 (97,3,0 and 97,2,1 and 97,1,2 and 97,0,3), but for four groups then each of these can have the last number divided into the 4th group.   For example the final 0 only has 1 way, but the 1 could be 0,1 or 1,0 and the 2 could be 2,0 or 1,1 or 0,2.
I was doing a programming problem (Advent of Code 2015 Day 15) and greatly overestimated how long it would take to brute-force it.  I ended up with 176,952 combinations for 100 items and 4 groups.  Maybe my google-fu isn't as good as I thought, but I've tried searching for something for about 30 minutes and couldn't find what I was looking for.

what should the formula give you, precisely?

i.e., for n=100 and m=4, how many combinations do you count for 25, 25, 25, 25?

Pretty sure you should get $176851$. Which is $\binom{103}{3}$.

Is this what you're looking for? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Clarification requested: For $~i \in {1,2,3,4},~$ let $~x_i~$ denote the number of items assigned to Group-$i.~$  Then, it looks like you are interested in the number of solutions to $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 100,$$  where $~x_1, ~x_2, ~x_3, ~x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.~$ $~\color{red}{\text{Is this correct ?}}~$ If so, then the previous comments have answered your question.  If this is not correct, then please explain, very clearly, why this is not correct.

If Stars and Bars theory is relevant to you, see also this article.

Here's a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

@BrunoAndrades I think stars and bars is it, if you want to provide that as an answer I'll accept it.

@ebenezer Just 1 option for 25,25,25,25.

@RobinSparrow You're right, I was using a global counter and not resetting it after the sample that had just two items and called it 101 times, thanks.

This is what's called stars and bars. The theorem exactly states that the number of ways to distribute $n$ objects among $m$ boxes in the way you've described is $\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}$. The proof of this fact is by establishing a bijection with the set of permutations of $n$ indistinguishable stars and $m-1$ indistinguishable bars. Each such distribution of objects will give as a permutation in the following manner. If box $b_i$ has $n_i$ elements, we'll place between the $(i-1)$-th bar and the $i$-th bar $n_i$ stars (taking the $0$-th and $m$-th bar to be non existent). It's easy to see that this is indeed a bijection, as you can construct an inverse.
Then, we just need to prove that the number of such permutations is what I claimed. Notice there's in total $(n+m-1)!$ permutations when I distinguish the stars and bars, since that's just the number of objects factorial, on the other hand, each permutation is double counted for every different permutation of the bars and of the stars, and there are $n!(m-1)!$ of them. All in all
$$\#\text{permutations}=\frac{(n+m-1)!}{n!(m-1)!}=\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}$$
as we wanted

This applied to your particular case of $n=100$ and $m=4$ will give you a total of $\binom{103}3=176851$ different configurations
